# How can I double underline a text inside a html table cell?

Tags: html, css, html-table

Both underline should be of length corresponding to the text content. I've come across another similar question where the accepted solution was to use

```
.doubleUnderline {
text-decoration:underline;
border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
```

But this is not what I wanted. I want the length of the double underline to be equal to the length of the text content.

Comment: What do you mean? It works fine [**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/Vt82L/)

Comment: @Ruddy. not with any padding it doesn't. http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/Vt82L/1/

Comment: @Paulie_D Who said anything about padding?

Comment: @Ruddy Who said anything about a span ?

Comment: @Paulie_D Me... Because they wanted it around text. So use a `span`.

Comment: Because it's more logical to use a `span` around text?

Comment: @BeatAlex It is when your want to double underline something.

Comment: Headings are text aren't they? Perhaps a span inside the specific element....then the span works. I agree.

Comment: I'm on your side @Ruddy

Comment: @Paulie_D Are you really trying to say its wrong? They haven't told us what the text is or how it is being used... So I gave a **comment** (not an answer) to show them it does work using normal text. If the OP has a problem with it using `<h1>` etc then they should state that.

Comment: @Paulie_D you can always use `inline-block`

Comment: @Ruddy I've edited the DEMO fiddle that you created. and thats the problem Im having.

Comment: @abhayK You going to link us? Please add a link to your comment or the question.

Comment: @Ruddy sorry http://jsfiddle.net/Vt82L/2/ is the link

Comment: @abhayK [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/Vt82L/3/) put a span around the text you want to have it

Comment: @abhayK Np, I will let BeatAlex have this. Please accept there answer as it is correct.

Comment: @BeatAlex Np, its mainly because my name is Alex... and you did beat me to write an answer :P So BeatAlex indeed!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've whipped two examples.

With block elements (like `p`) you can use `inline-block` so it doesn't go the full length of page and just the text.

```css
span{
  border-bottom:1px solid #000;
  text-decoration:underline;
}
        
p{
  border-bottom:1px solid #000;
  text-decoration:underline;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<span>This is a bit of text for you</span>
<br>
<p>This is some text for you too</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<td> 
  <span style="border-bottom:double black;">
    Grand Total : ###,###,###.00
  </span>
</td>
```

hope this works out for you :)

ps: if you need to adjust the width use at least 3px. otherwise it will not shown as double underline

Comment: This should really be the answer. Just note that the height needs to be minimum `3px`, or it will appear as a single underline.

Answer (score 1):

There is a proposed [`text-decoration-style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration-style) rule in CSS3 that has a value "double", but it's not supported in browsers yet.

```css
.example { 
    text-decoration-line: underline;
    text-decoration-style: double;
}
```

```html
<p class="example">This is how it looks</p>
```